# Close an ionic 2 searchbar

Tags: events, triggers, searchbar, ionic2

How to "`close`" my search bar when a user select a search result? I would like to try with a trigger on the cancel event but how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a `*ngIf` directive to determine when to show or hide the search bar